# Potential floating point issue with cosine acceleration curve

Tags: math, floating-point, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am using a cosine curve to apply a force on an object between the range [0, pi]. By my calculations, that should give me a sine curve for the velocity which, at `t=pi/2` should have a velocity of 1.0f

However, for the simplest of examples, I get a top speed of 0.753.

Now if this is a floating point issue, that is fine, but that is a very significant error so I am having trouble accepting that it is (and if it is, why is there such a huge error computing these values).

Some code:

```
// the function that gives the force to apply (totalTime = pi, maxForce = 1.0 in this example)
return ((Mathf.Cos(time * (Mathf.PI / totalTime)) * maxForce));


// the engine stores this value and in the next fixed update applies it to the rigidbody
// the mass is 1 so isn't affecting the result
engine.ApplyAccelerateForce(applyingForce * ship.rigidbody2D.mass);
```

**Update**

There is no gravity being applied to the object, no other objects in the world for it to interact with and no drag. I'm also using a `RigidBody2D` so the object is only moving on the plane.

**Update 2**

Ok have tried a super simple example and I get the result I am expecting so there must be something in my code. Will update once I have isolated what is different.

For the record, super simple code:

```
float forceThisFrame;
float startTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    forceThisFrame = 0.0f;
    startTime = Time.fixedTime;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float time = Time.fixedTime - startTime;

    if(time <= Mathf.PI)
    {

        forceThisFrame = Mathf.Cos (time);

        if(time >= (Mathf.PI /2.0f)- 0.01f && time <= (Mathf.PI /2.0f) + 0.01f)
        {
            print ("Speed: " + rigidbody2D.velocity);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        forceThisFrame = 0.0f;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody2D.AddForce(forceThisFrame * Vector2.up);
}
```

**Update 3**

I have changed my original code to match the above example as near as I can (remaining differences listed below) and I still get the discrepancy.

Here [are my results of velocity against time](https://gist.github.com/thk123/8042341). Neither of them make sense to me, with a constant force of 1N, that should result in a linear velocity function `v(t) = t` but that isn't quite what is produced by either example.

*Remaining differences:*

- The code that is "calculating" the force (now just returning 1) is being run via a non-unity DLL, though the code itself resides within a Unity DLL (can explain more but can't believe this is relevant!)
- The behaviour that is applying the force to the rigid body is a separate behaviour.
- <strike>One is moving a cube in an empty enviroment, the other is moving a Model3D and there is a plane nearby</strike> - tried a cube with same code in broken project, same problem

Other than that, I can't see any difference and I certainly can't see why any of those things would affect it. They both apply a force of 1 on an object every fixed update.

Comment: I'm assuming there's no obstacles for it to hit, but is there gravity affecting the object? Is there friction applied by ground/water or something similar?

Comment: Ah yeah should have mentioned, no drag, no gravity, I'll  update :)

Comment: Was just trying out enabling interpolation on the rigid body and tidied up my prints so could easily see the max speed and it consistently obtained ~0.9, putting the prints back in and I go back to getting speeds of 0.8 so could be some kind of frame rate issue.

Comment: What is the time steps? And is there any initial speed?

Comment: You know that twice integrating a cosine results in -cosine? Try it with [`Wolfram Alfa`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+int+cos%28x%29)

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto timestep is 0.02 (doing all this in Unity, the force is being applied in the `FixedUpdate`). I don't follow your second point?

@ja72 Yes... not sure why you are mentioning this? If my acceleration/force curve is cosine, then the velocity is the (single) integral of that which is sine. Observing the speeds they are following a sine curve (going from 0 and back to 0 in the range of pi) the issue is they don't quite reach 1.0.

Comment: What happens if you just try `(Mathf.Cos(time))`?

Comment: Set the force to 1 and see whether the velocity at time π/2 is π/2. This will tell you whether there is some scaling in the physics software.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that gives 1.479999 (but in my simple, correct example, gives the correct 1.579999).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have posted the results of the simple force being applied in my code and the simple example. Any ideas what could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: @T.Kiley: There are places in the data where the time jumps by .12 instead of .02 or where it stalls and does not increase at all. Worse, the speed changes do not match; in the “Broken” data, the time increases from .02 to .14 (six times normal) while the speed increases from .02 to .04 (normal). Something is odd in the physics simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a multi-part problem that started with me not fully understanding `Update` vs. `FixedUpdate` in Unity, see [this question on GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67534/why-do-my-velocity-estimates-have-such-a-large-margin-of-error/67660) for more info on that part.

My "fix" from that was advancing a timer that went with the fixed update so as to not apply the force wrong. The problem, as demonstrated by Eric Postpischil was because the `FixedUpdate`, despite its name, is not called every 0.02s but instead at most every 0.02s. The fix for this was, in my update to apply some scaling to the force to apply to accomodate for missed fixed updates. My code ended up looking something like:

*Called From Update*

```
float oldTime = time;
time = Time.fixedTime - startTime;
float variableFixedDeltaTime = time - oldTime;
float fixedRatio = variableFixedDeltaTime / Time.fixedDeltaTime;

if(time <= totalTime)
{
    applyingForce = forceFunction.GetValue(time) * fixedRatio;

    Vector2 currentVelocity = ship.rigidbody2D.velocity;
    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(ship.transform.right.x, ship.transform.right.y);
    float velocityAlongDir = Vector2.Dot(currentVelocity, direction);
    float velocityPrediction = velocityAlongDir + (applyingForce * lDeltaTime);

    if(time > 0.0f && // we are not interested if we are just starting
       ((velocityPrediction < 0.0f  && velocityAlongDir > 0.0f ) ||
       (velocityPrediction > 0.0f  && velocityAlongDir < 0.0f ) ))
    {
        float ratio = Mathf.Abs((velocityAlongDir / (applyingForce * lDeltaTime)));
        applyingForce = applyingForce * ratio;

        // We have reversed the direction so we must have arrived
        Deactivate();
    }

    engine.ApplyAccelerateForce(applyingForce);
}
```

Where `ApplyAccelerateForce` does:

```
public void ApplyAccelerateForce(float requestedForce)
{
    forceToApply += requestedForce;
}
```

*Called from FixedUpdate*

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(forceToApply * new Vector2(transform.right.x, transform.right.y));
forceToApply = 0.0f;
```

Answer (score 2):

For the cosine case this isn't a floating point issue, per se, it's an integration issue.

[In your 'fixed' acceleration case there are clearly also minor floating point issues].

Obviously acceleration is proportional to force (*`F = ma`*) but you can't just simply add the acceleration to get the velocity, especially if the time interval between frames is not constant.

Simplifying things by assuming that the inter-frame acceleration is constant, and therefore following *`v = u + at`* (or alternately *`∂v = a.∂t`*) you need to scale the effect of the acceleration in proportion to the time elapsed since the last frame.  It follows that the smaller *`∂t`* is, the more accurate your integration.

Comment: OP, have you tried using time.deltaTime or time.smoothDeltaTime instead of hand-writing your time update code?

Comment: @theodox When I used the Time.deltaTime I got an [issue](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67534/why-do-my-velocity-estimates-have-such-a-large-margin-of-error) when estimating my next velocity. I shall investigate smoothDeltaTime.

Comment: This, along with Eric's comment has pointed me in the right direction.  The problem came from the fact that FixedUpdate, despite its name, does not necessarily get called at fixed intervals. I'll write up what I ended up doing if that's ok?

Comment: For lurkers it's also worth mentioning that FixedUpdate and Update don't necessearily fire at the same frequency - you may get more than one FixedUpdate in between updates.  This answer is a good reference: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10993/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-fixedupdat.html